# yum - Install a package with just the name and version

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

From what I know about yum, I can specify the name of an rpm, like this:

```
yum install zlib
```

I can also specify the whole darn name, like this:

```
yum install zlib-1.2.3-27.el6.x86_64
```

Is there a way to specify an intermediate filename? Such as just the name and version, like this:

```
yum install zlib-1.2.3
```

When I try, I always get

```
No package zlib-1.2.3 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Answer (score 4):

Try throwing a * on the end:

`yum install zlib-1.2.3*`